# Array Index out of bounds think there is a specfic line

Tags: java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100 at ham.main(ham.java:34)

line 34 on my console says if (h[c] == 1)

i wrote a code to generate hamming code..i am getting the javaindexoutbounds exception..i even gave absurdly large array sizes to counter tht..still not working! 
The array is outbounds even thou there plenty of space for the array

the line 27 might be a mistake...checking for c

```
 import java.util.*;

public class ham {
public static void main(String ar[]) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input no. of bits");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[100]; // user's input
    int h[] = new int[100]; // hamming code array
    System.out.println("i/p the data");
    int i = 1, j = 1, pb = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
        a[i] = s.nextInt();
    i = 1;

    while (i < n + 1) {
        if (j == pb) // if the index is a parity bit leave it
        {
            j++;
            pb = pb * 2;
        } else {
            h[j] = a[i];
            j++;
            i++;
        } // else copy the data bits from a[] to h[]
    }

    int c = 0, counter = 0; // to fill the parity bits(k)
    for (int k = 1; k <= j; k = 2 * k) {
        c = k;
        while (c <= j) // 'j' is position of the last data bit in h[]
        {
            for (c = k; c < (c + k); c++) {
                if (h[c] == 1)   // this is line 34
                    counter++;
            }
            c = c + k + 1;
        }
        if (counter % 2 == 0)
            h[k] = 0;
        else
            h[k] = 1;
    }
    System.out.println("hamming code is");
    for (i = 1; i <= j; i++)
        System.out.print(h[i] + " ");
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please include the compiler error? It's not fair to ask us to trawl through this code with no line numbers nor any hint of what is going wrong.

Comment: Tell us what line throws the exception and indicate it with a comment in the code. The exception message will tell you this.

Comment: You seem to be indexing your arrays from 1 rather than 0. The "<=" comparisons make me think you run out of bounds right there.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
 at ham.main(ham.java:34)

Comment: line 34 on my console says if (h[c] == 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if (h[c] == 1)` test is causing the exception.

Your `h` array has a fixed size of `100`, but the maximum value of `c` seems to depend on the user's input, `n`. You will need to figure out how to dynamically determine your array sizes, depending on the user input.

Comment: hmmm as in int a[] = new int[100]; // user's input
  int h[] = new int[a.length]; // hamming code array

Comment: I meant 'n', which comes from the Scanner. I've modified my answer to include this detail.

Comment: hmm i put inputh[] = new int [n]; throws an another error at me

Comment: You have to figure out the correct size to use. The right size *depends* on n, but is NOT n. You will have to analyze your algorithm to figure out the right formula for the size. It is too complex for me to figure out in a reasonable amount of time, so I can't help you there.